# Changing current-menu-item in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm designing a website for a client which has a long menu, which stems to another line. I want to add a different colour for the menu items that are on the second line, so i need to change the current-menu-item only for those menu items - i assigned a class of .nav2 to those menu items originally in order to change the a:hover for said items.

If anyone could help me with that it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here as your question was very confusing:

```
.current-menu-item.nav2  {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Apologies for making the question confusing. I basically want to make the .current-menu-item for the second row of the navigation (to which i assigned .nav2) different to the top row of the navigation. Hope that makes more sense. Your suggestion worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: If you post some html it will be much easier to help

Answer (score -1):

For wordpress:

```
.menu .current_page_item a
{
  background:#000;
}
```