# Change current menu item background

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, background, menuitem

I found a related question but I can't get help from it:
[Changing current-menu-item in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809410/changing-current-menu-item-in-wordpress).

**Code:**
I am using this code to display navigation menu in WordPress.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header-menu ul.menu li:hover > a,
#header-menu ul.menu a:focus,
#header-menu .menu .current-menu-item > a,
#header-menu .menu .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#header-menu .menu .current_page_item > a,
#header-menu .menu .current_page_ancestor > a {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**Question:**
I want to change the background color of current menu item but when I select next page it doesn't change the color of menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **add the CSS rule in each page** you want it to assign style to the HTML elements.

So it's better if you **put the CSS in a file** and ***include it in all the pages where the style is required***.

So save the CSS rule in a file say **`1.css`**.

And in the HTML page **`<head>`** section write the following statement-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
```